# identify if the file is open before uploading in the fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How can I determine if the file the user is uploading is closed before pressing the upload button when using a FileUpload Dialog control in C# ASP.net. This will prevent the user from pushing a file with unsaved data to the server for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. The file will either:

- A) Be pushed without flushed changes, or
- B) Cause a problem if the file can't be opened to push the content (i.e. open with a lock of sorts) - the point at which this occurs is most likely within the 'Open file' dialog, however, so a user system issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is (somewhat) possible but requires a lot of effort and close control of your end users environment which may not be possible.

The steps in general are as follows:

1: You can use a virtual file system like CBFS or other open source libraries (sorry I've no practical experience with anything other than CBFS) - http://www.eldos.com/solutions/solutions-for-developers.php#commchannel

2: Create the virtual file system so that it maps to either database storage or server side storage

3: Map this as a directory on the end users systems

4: As long as the end users are creating and modifying files within this share or you only accept files from this share then you can check for open file handles and if so prevent the upload

Comment: Thanks @Johnv2020. After discussing this with the Project Owner they have decided to reduce that requirement to a messagebox warning the user to ensure the file is closed. At this point in the Development that seems to be the smartest way.

Comment: Amazing the way a project owner will change specifications once they realise the solution will cost money & take time isn't it..

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the user is editing your file. Word for example and Notepad starting with Windows Vista or 7 do lock the file so nobody else can write to them. In this case it is as easy as to open the file writable and check if you get an IOException.

```
static bool IsWriteProtected(string file)
{
    try
    {
        using (File.OpenWrite(file)) ;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Comment: This only allows for checking _server side_ files

Comment: Correct @m.edmondso I need to check client side before the file is pushed. My thought is short of creating an activeX control it is not possible, but I wanted to check with the community and see if anyone devised a way yet.

Comment: ups sorry. There seems no way for regular Java Script in the Browser to access your local file system. If you have enough rights then this link should help: http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm